# ExtJS row height

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have 2 grids (`Ext.grid.Panel`): the left one and the right one.

Both grids have same amount of rows. But one of the left grid columns is a checkbox, so left rows are 1px higher.

How can I set right row height according to left row height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Try This...
> >
> > //Get height of the first grid row panel  var row =
> >     firstgrid.getView().getNode("row number of first grid panel which you
> >     want increase");
>
> var height = Ext.get(row).getHeight();
>
> > //Apply the first grid row heigt to second grid row
> >
> > var row = secondgrid.getView().getNode("row number of first grid panel
> >     which you want increase");
>
> var height = Ext.get(row).setHeight(height);